# MySQL Replication (1 Master, 3 Slaves): When 1 slave is dumping a big database, the other slaves lag behind

Tags: mysql, replication

I have 1 master and 3 replicated slaves.

Every night I perform the following on slave 1:

```
STOP SLAVE SQL_THREAD
mysqldump ...
START SLAVE
```

The dump takes about 45minutes, in that time Slave 2 and 3 also lags behind the master, which I dont really understand why, as far as I know Slave 2 and 3 should not be affected by the actions on Slave 1?

Comment: can this be a network issue ? goes the dump also over the network ? if so, you can test it with a local dump

Comment: seems dump data transfer is choking your bandwidth so first take backup on same server locally and archive it here then move to your desired path.